# Simple PyGame Connect 4

Tags: python, game, pygame

I've made a simple connect 4 game using PyGame. I'm new to python and haven't completely perfected this. I know it's inefficient but I can't tell exactly HOW to fix it? Could someone help me out? Would be greatly appreciated.

```py
import pygame
from colors import *
import random
pygame.init()

size = (320, 280)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Connect 4 but Worse")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

turn = 0

class Space():

    def __init__(self):
        self.color = WHITE
        self.height = 40
        self.width = 40
        self.x = 5
        self.y = 5
    def Draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, 40, 40])

x_list = [5, 50, 95, 140, 185, 230, 275]
y_list = [5, 50, 95, 140, 185, 230]

spaces_list = []
x_counter = 0
y_counter = 0

for i in range(42):
    slot = Space()
    slot.color = WHITE
    slot.height = 40
    slot.width = 40
    slot.x = x_list[x_counter]
    slot.y = y_list[y_counter]

    spaces_list.append(slot)

    x_counter += 1
    if x_counter == 7:
        y_counter +=1
        x_counter = 0

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            (posx,posy) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if posx > 5 and posx < 45:
                if spaces_list[35].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[35].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[35].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[28].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[28].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[28].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[21].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[21].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[21].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[14].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[14].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[14].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[7].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[7].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[7].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[0].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[0].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[0].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
            if posx > 50 and posx < 90:
                if spaces_list[36].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[36].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[36].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[29].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[29].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[29].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[22].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[22].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[22].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[15].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[15].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[15].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[8].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[8].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[8].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[1].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[1].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[1].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
            if posx > 95 and posx < 135:
                if spaces_list[37].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[37].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[37].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[30].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[30].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[30].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[23].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[23].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[23].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[16].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[16].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[16].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[9].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[9].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[9].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[2].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[2].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[2].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
            if posx > 140 and posx < 180:
                if spaces_list[38].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[38].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[38].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[31].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[31].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[31].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[24].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[24].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[24].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[17].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[17].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[17].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[10].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[10].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[10].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[3].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[3].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[3].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
            if posx > 185 and posx < 225:
                if spaces_list[39].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[39].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[39].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[32].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[32].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[32].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[25].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[25].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[25].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[18].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[18].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[18].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[11].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[11].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[11].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[4].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[4].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[4].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
            if posx > 230 and posx < 270:
                if spaces_list[40].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[40].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[40].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[33].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[33].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[33].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[26].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[26].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[26].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[19].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[19].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[19].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[12].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[12].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[12].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[5].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[5].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[5].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
            if posx > 275:
                if spaces_list[41].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[41].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[41].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[34].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[34].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[34].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[27].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[27].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[27].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[20].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[20].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[20].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[13].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[13].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[13].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0
                elif spaces_list[6].color == WHITE:
                    if turn == 0:
                        spaces_list[6].color = RED
                        turn = 1
                    elif turn == 1:
                        spaces_list[6].color = YELLOW
                        turn = 0

    screen.fill(BLUE)

    counter = 0

    for items in spaces_list:
        spaces_list[counter].Draw(screen)
        counter += 1

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Did you ever think about how you could calculate the game coordinates (0..6, 0..5) from the screen coordinates (0..319, 0..239)? That can be done a lot easier than having this huge `if then elif` cascade. Try to explain how this works, either to a human, or to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). You could also have a look at [other solutions to the same task](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=connect4).

Comment: Instead of using a long if/else block, consider using a dictionary.

Comment: how can I use a dictionary to fix it?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: oops, sorry about that. Should I post another question with the revised code?

Comment: Yep! If you wish, that'd be the best course of action!

Answer (score 9):

### Space

```
class Space():

    def __init__(self):
        self.color = WHITE
        self.height = 40
        self.width = 40
        self.x = 5
        self.y = 5
    def Draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, 40, 40])
```

According to PEP-8, methods should use `snake_case`.  `MixedCase` is reserved for class names.  So `Draw` should be `draw`.  Also, there should be a blank line before `def draw(...)`.

The members `height` and `width` are never used.  The members `x` and `y` are only used inside of the `Space` class (although they are changed externally shortly after creating the `Space` object.  Perhaps these should be passed in as arguments to the constructor.  Also, these should be named with a leading underscore to convey they are non-public members.

Perhaps better, instead of constructing the list `[self._x, self._y, self._width, self._height]` every time you draw the space object, you could store a list with this information:

```
class Space():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.color = WHITE
        self._rect = [x, y, 40, 40]

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color, self._rect)
```

### Spaces

Utilizing the new constructor:

```
x_list = [5, 50, 95, 140, 185, 230, 275]
y_list = [5, 50, 95, 140, 185, 230]

spaces_list = []
x_counter = 0
y_counter = 0

for i in range(42):
    slot = Space(x_list[x_counter], y_list[y_counter]

    spaces_list.append(slot)

    x_counter += 1
    if x_counter == 7:
        y_counter += 1
        x_counter = 0
```

This construction technique is very verbose.  More over, you've got magic numbers scattered around (`42`, `7`), which makes the code hard to understand.  Where did these numbers come from?  What do they mean?

You could help by declaring named constants `COLUMNS = 7` and `TOTAL_SPACES = 42`, and then using these symbol names, but that is missing the point.  You've got an `x_list` with 7 entries, so `COLUMNS = len(x_list)` makes it so that if you add an extra column to `x_list`, the `COLUMNS` value will be automatically computed.  Same for `TOTAL_SPACES`, it would be the product of the lengths of `x_list` and `y_list`.

But storing each `Space` object in a 42 element 1-dimensional list is just plain wrong.  You've got a 2-d grid of spaces.  You should store it as a 2-d structure.  A list of lists:

```
spaces_grid = [ [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...] ]
```

You could then access the spaces like `spaces_grid[x][y]`, with \$0 \le x \le 6\$ and \$0 \le y \le 5\$.

The list comprehension expression `[Space(x, y) for y in y_list]` will create a list representing one column of that grid, using a particular fixed value of `x`, taking each `y` value from successive elements of `y_list`, and calling the `Space(x, y)` constructor for those values.  We then need to then repeat that for each value of `x` in `x_list`:

```
spaces_grid = [ [Space(x, y) for y in y_list] for x in x_list]
```

And done in one line.

### Click on Column

```
        (posx,posy) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if posx > 5 and posx < 45:
            ... 42 lines omitted ...
        if posx > 50 and posx < 90:
            ... 42 lines omitted ...
        if posx > 95 and posx < 135:
            ... 42 lines omitted ...
        if posx > 140 and posx < 180:
            ... 42 lines omitted ...
        if posx > 185 and posx < 225:
            ... 42 lines omitted ...
        if posx > 230 and posx < 270:
            ... 42 lines omitted ...
        if posx > 275:
            ... 42 lines omitted ...
```

Magic numbers galore!  How much pain would it be to change the disc size from 40 pixels to 55 pixels?

When the user click the mouse button, you get an `(posx, posy)` coordinate.  You need to convert that `posx` value to a column index.  The `bisect` module can help.  It will search in a list of value for the position to insert another value at.  We're not inserting here, but using it would allow us to quickly determine the column based on the `posx` and the `x_list`.

```
column_num = bisect.bisect(x_list, posx) - 1
```

You could then validate that you haven't clicked between columns:

```
if column_num >= 0 and posx < x_list[column_num] + 40:
    column = spaces_grid[column_num]
```

Apologies for the magic number `40`.  Turn this into a named constant too.

Now you can work with `column` and determine how far down the `column` the coloured disc should fall.

```
            if spaces_list[35].color == WHITE:
                if turn == 0:
                    spaces_list[35].color = RED
                    turn = 1
                elif turn == 1:
                    spaces_list[35].color = YELLOW
                    turn = 0
            elif spaces_list[28].color == WHITE:
                if turn == 0:
                    spaces_list[28].color = RED
                    turn = 1
                elif turn == 1:
                    spaces_list[28].color = YELLOW
                    turn = 0
            elif spaces_list[21].color == WHITE:
                if turn == 0:
                    spaces_list[21].color = RED
                    turn = 1
                elif turn == 1:
                    spaces_list[21].color = YELLOW
                    turn = 0
            elif spaces_list[14].color == WHITE:
                if turn == 0:
                    spaces_list[14].color = RED
                    turn = 1
                elif turn == 1:
                    spaces_list[14].color = YELLOW
                    turn = 0
            elif spaces_list[7].color == WHITE:
                if turn == 0:
                    spaces_list[7].color = RED
                    turn = 1
                elif turn == 1:
                    spaces_list[7].color = YELLOW
                    turn = 0
            elif spaces_list[0].color == WHITE:
                if turn == 0:
                    spaces_list[0].color = RED
                    turn = 1
                elif turn == 1:
                    spaces_list[0].color = YELLOW
                    turn = 0
```

Yeouch!  This is just one copy of the 7 blocks of "... 42 lines omitted ..." above.

With the `column` list computed above, you could change this code to read:

```
    if column[5].color == WHITE:
        if turn == 0:
            column[5].color = RED
            turn = 1
        elif turn == 1:
            column[5].color = YELLOW
            turn = 0
    elif column[4].color == WHITE:
        if turn == 0:
            column[4].color = RED
            turn = 1
        elif turn == 1:
            column[4].color = YELLOW
            turn = 0
    elif column[3].color == WHITE:
        if turn == 0:
            column[3].color = RED
            turn = 1
        elif turn == 1:
            column[3].color = YELLOW
            turn = 0
    elif column[2].color == WHITE:
        if turn == 0:
            column[2].color = RED
            turn = 1
        elif turn == 1:
            column[2].color = YELLOW
            turn = 0
    elif column[1].color == WHITE:
        if turn == 0:
            column[1].color = RED
            turn = 1
        elif turn == 1:
            column[1].color = YELLOW
            turn = 0
    elif column[0].color == WHITE:
        if turn == 0:
            column[0].color = RED
            turn = 1
        elif turn == 1:
            column[0].color = YELLOW
            turn = 0
```

And delete the other 6 copies of the block.  This is a huge improvement, but it is clear we can do better.  We are doing exactly the same operation on the `Space` objects starting at `column[5]` and going down to `column[0]`.  This screams loop!

```
    for space in column[::-1]:
        if space.color == WHITE:
            space.color = RED if turn == 0 else YELLOW
            turn = 1 - turn
            break
```

Breaking this down:

- `column[::-1]` reverses the list of `Space` objects, so `column[5]` is returned first, and `column[0]` is returned last
- When we find a `space` with `space.color == WHITE`, we do some stuff, and then `break` out of the `for` loop.
- A ternary `... if ... else ...` is used to assign `RED` or `YELLOW` to the space, based on whether `turn == 0` is true or not.
- `turn = 1 - turn` will flip `turn` back and forth between `1` and `0`.

42 lines reduced down to 6.

### Draw the grid

What the code used to look like:

```
    counter = 0

    for items in spaces_list:
        spaces_list[counter].Draw(screen)
        counter += 1
```

This was odd, since you were looping over all of the items in `spaces_list`, and then ignoring the `Space` that was stored in `items` on each iteration.  Instead, you added a counter, which you manually incremented, and then looked up the element at `spaces_list[counter]`, which would be the same items that was already stored in `items`.  You could have simply called `items.Draw(screen)`.

We no longer have `spaces_list`.  Instead, we have `spaces_grid`, which is a 2d grid of `Space` objects.  We'll draw this by looping over the columns in the grid, and then loop over the space in each column, and draw that space directly.

```
    for column in spaces_grid:
        for space in column:
            space.draw(screen)
```

### Miscellaneous

- You import `random` but never use it.
- You should separate imports from code with a blank line.
- You shouldn't split the mainline code up with some code before classes are declared, and some code after it.
- I'm not sure what module `colors` is.  I don't have it, and needed to get the color constants a different way.

### Reworked Code

Here is my reworked code.  It is a wee bit shorter than your original implementation:

```
import pygame, bisect

class Space():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.color = WHITE
        self._rect = [x, y, 40, 40]

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color, self._rect)

pygame.init()

YELLOW = pygame.color.THECOLORS['yellow']
WHITE = pygame.color.THECOLORS['white']
BLUE = pygame.color.THECOLORS['blue']
RED = pygame.color.THECOLORS['red']

size = (320, 280)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Connect 4 but Worse")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

turn = 0

x_list = [5, 50, 95, 140, 185, 230, 275]
y_list = [5, 50, 95, 140, 185, 230]

spaces_grid = [ [Space(x, y) for y in y_list] for x in x_list]

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            (posx,posy) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            column_num = bisect.bisect(x_list, posx) - 1

            if column_num >= 0 and posx < x_list[column_num] + 40:
                column = spaces_grid[column_num]

                for space in column[::-1]:
                    if space.color == WHITE:
                        space.color = RED if turn == 0 else YELLOW
                        turn = 1 - turn
                        break

    screen.fill(BLUE)

    for column in spaces_grid:
        for space in column:
            space.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

There is still much work that should be done on it.  For instance, I don't think the `x_list` and `y_list` is the best way to determine positions.  I would rework things along these lines:

```
DISC_SIZE = 40
GAP = 5
COLUMNS = 7
ROWS = 6

size = (GAP + (DISC_SIZE + GAP) * COLUMNS, GAP + (DISC_SIZE + GAP) * ROWS)
```

And then the `(x, y)` coordinates for each `Space` could be computed from a row and column number.  Bigger/smaller discs?  No problem! Larger gap?  No problem!  Different grid size?  No problem!  Just adjust these 4 numbers and your game grid is completely resized.

### Winning

You eventually will need a 4-in-a-row check.  Let me get you started.  If `player` holds the current player's colour, then:

```
a_horizontal_win = all(spaces_grid[x+i][y] == player for i in range(4))
```

will test if the spaces starting at `(x,y)`, passing through `(x+1,y)`, `(x+2,y)`, and ending at `(x+3,y)` all contain the that player's colour.  You just need to move the starting `(x,y)` location around to all the legal starting points, and do something similar for vertical, and the two diagonals.

Comment: I see, thank you. Those numbers referred to each specific space on the game board, although I'm aware that's not a great way of doing things

Comment: @Moleman I've continued the review, and addressed the code duplication in the `if...elif...` tree.  You should find it an improvement even over Carcigenicate's solution, which I see you tried to implement in your question post edit.

Answer (score 6):

I wish I could make a more comprehensive suggestion regarding the gigantic mass under `while not done:`. The sheer amount of duplication there is unsustainable.  I'm pretty tired though, so I'll have to stick to simpler issues.

In that chunk, you do something along these lines, *many* times:

```
if turn == 0:
    spaces_list[#].color = RED
    turn = 1

 elif turn == 1:
    spaces_list[#].color = YELLOW
    turn = 0
```

At the very least, I'd try to work on that. Something like creating a `toggle_state` function:

```
def toggle_function(index: int) -> None:
    global turn

    if turn == 0:
        spaces_list[index].color = RED
        turn = 1

    elif turn == 1:
        spaces_list[index].color = YELLOW
        turn = 0
```

Now, you can do

```
if spaces_list[35].color == WHITE:
    toggle_state(35)

elif spaces_list[28].color == WHITE:
    toggle_state(28)
```

Instead of

```
if spaces_list[35].color == WHITE:
    if turn == 0:
        spaces_list[35].color = RED
        turn = 1
    elif turn == 1:
        spaces_list[35].color = YELLOW
        turn = 0
elif spaces_list[28].color == WHITE:
    if turn == 0:
        spaces_list[28].color = RED
        turn = 1
    elif turn == 1:
        spaces_list[28].color = YELLOW
        turn = 0
```

You could even really push your luck with readability (although it will still be better), and have `toggle_state` return whether or not it made a change:

```
def toggle_state(index: int) -> bool:
    global turn

    if spaces_list[index].color == WHITE:
        if turn == 0:
            spaces_list[index].color = RED
            turn = 1

        elif turn == 1:
            spaces_list[index].color = YELLOW
            turn = 0

        return True

    else:
        return False
```

Now, you can do:

```
toggle_state(35) or toggle_state(28) or . . .
```

or, something like

```
any(toggle_state(i) for i in [35, 28, . . .]
```

Things to note though:

- This is still bad. In the first suggestion, you're still needing to refer to the index number in both the `== WHITE` check, and when passing the number to the `toggle_state`. This kind of duplication can leads to errors, although it's still better than your current solution.
- The second suggestion introduces weird behavior conceptually. Why is `toggle_state` returning whether or not it did anything? Because I couldn't think of a cleaner way to do it. It doesn't make a ton of sense, but it still allows for much cleaner code.
- Both rely on `global turn`, and this immediately suggests that the code stinks (it does). Ideally, doing something like returning a state including `turn` and `spaces_list` would be more proper, but I think that detracts from the main point here: reducing duplication.

Beyond that though, you have too many magic numbers floating around with no clear purpose. Ideally, you should aim for that chunk to be simplified using a loop or similar construct. As long as you have everything in a rigid, hardcoded style though, that will be difficult.

Comment: very helpful, thank you. that cut down quite a bit of my code. I'll try to work on some type of function to replace the if/else block

Comment: @Moleman No problem. I'm not sure how practiced you are with handling duplication, but the general "formula" is to take two pieces of duplicated code like I did above, and look at what's the same and what's different. Make the identical parts the body of a function, and make the different parts parameters of the function. That alone will cover most cases when trying to reduce duplication.